# How to make a face between circles?

Tags: modeling

trying to make a face between the selected circles for a disk shape
 [image] SHIFT TAB should let me select edges then i should be able to make a face, correct? however, the selection to select vertices, edges isn't showing up and when i hit f, a third larger circle appears? what gives? beginner here 
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46342/is-there-a-way-to-fill-the-area-between-two-circles/46351#46351 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88931/connect-vertices-from-inner-circle-to-outer-circle and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49940/how-can-i-connect-the-top-loop-to-the-down-loop-with-faces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first join all the paths /shapes by selecting them

[image]

hit spacebar search and search "join"

[image]

or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Once those are one shape, press <kbd>Space</kbd>  and type in search "convert to"

[image]

Here you can see two options, select *Convert to mesh*

[image]

Once that is converted into mesh, go to *Edit Mode*, and start Filling paths..

[image]

Select two edges in two separate paths and hit <kbd>F</kbd>, they will be connected.

[image]

[image]

Now select one edge and keep pressing <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: For the last part the "Bridge Edge Loop" command would be even more fitting.

Comment: @Leander, You are right. Appreciated. I'm sorry I forgot that at that moment.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a curve object. Curve objects are different than mehses. You cannot add faces to curves.

You can convert them to a mesh as stated on the other answser. but you can choose to keep them as curves.

To fill, just convert them to a 2d curve and select "both" as the Fill mode.
[image]

If you need more concentric rings, just duplicate one of the rings and resize.

[image]

If you must convert to mesh, then press Alt C in edit Mode, select convert curve to mesh. Enter edit mode, select all vertices and do "bridge edge loops"

[image]